# Advanced styling of labels on Vector Tiles (OpenLayers)

Tags: gis, openlayers, mbtiles, vector-tiles

I managed to use Natural Earth data to generate vector tiles, and serve it to the MapBox. I also use geoJSON data to show labels with country names.

Now, as you can see on these 2 animations - when zooming in the OpenLayers, labels have the same size, and no fade-in animation as it is the case in the MapBox example (among other things - formatting is also not in one line but in multiple lines etc.).

[image]
[image]

Is there any existing style for OL or some tutorial how to achieve this same effect?

Comment: Splitting lines can be done in the style function (`stringDivider` in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html)  For smoother animation try the `updateWhileAnimating` and `updateWhileInteracting` options https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html

Comment: You might be able to make use of the `wrapText` function used in https://github.com/openlayers/ol-mapbox-style/blob/master/src/stylefunction.js

Comment: Example using ol-mapbox-style only to produce a style for wrapped text https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-ok65q?file=/main.js - but if you already have a full mapbox style you could use ol-mapbox-style to style the whole map.

Comment: Thanks. I will use that stringDivider. I guess even text size could be calculated based on country size. The only thing I'm missing now is that fade-in animation when text shows (since for me now it is either visible or hidden)